# Заполнение нескольких инпутов из одной ссылки

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем так, в справочнике есть жалобы, объективные данные и диагноз а в форме есть соответствующие поля так же жалобы , объективные данные и диагноз. У каждой жалобы есть свои объективные данные и диагноз (все расставлено по категориям) Нужно сделать так чтоб когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку с жалобами то поле жалобы и остальные поля типа объективные и диагноз заполнялись автоматически. Как можно сделать. Есть такой код что нужно тут поменять чтобы реализовать задуманное ? `<script type="text/javascript">
function getText(el){
    document.getElementById('field').value = el.firstChild.data;
}
</script>`

а в ссылке пишу так `<a href="javascript:void(0)" ondblclick="getText(this)" id="text">1</a><br />`

Поля ввода выглядят вот так `<input type="text" id="field" value=""><br />`

Скрин страницы по требованиям 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <input id="pole" type="text" name="name" />
<input id="pole2" type="text" name="name" />
 
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('pole').value = 'zapolneno!' ; document.getElementById('pole2').value = 'zapolneno2!'">ссылка</a>
Нашел сам

Comment: дай хоть скрин страницы...